# How to query the date range of 1 record with the input date range in mongoDB using Parse server

Tags: node.js, mongodb, parse-server

I have a record as below:

```
{
  "_id":"iUgYHSxL1R",
  "fromDate":{"$date":"2020-08-03T00:00:00.000Z"},
  "toDate":{"$date":"2020-09-03T23:59:59.000Z"},
  "status":"occupied",
  "apartmentId":"gzEBXiH9HH",
  "bookingId":"A01066",
   "type":"daily"
}
```

And I have an input date of the range are:

```
fromDate: 2020-08-12T00:00:00.000Z
toDate: 2020-08-15T23:59:59.000Z
```

I used the following query with the desire to get the record as above, but it failed:

```
var query = helper.createQuery('Demo');
query.greaterThanOrEqualTo("fromDate", params.fromDate);
query.lessThanOrEqualTo("fromDate", params.toDate);
query.greaterThanOrEqualTo("toDate", params.fromDate);
query.lessThanOrEqualTo("toDate", params.toDate);

var apartmentStatusHistoryQuery = Parse.Query.or(query);
```

Comment: In what way did it fail? Did you get an error?